# PHP Email Form Stuck at Validation and causing server error 500

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to do a contact form on my website and when I hit the submit button it doesn't get past the the validation function.  It says there appears to be a problem with the forms, but I'm filling in all of the data.  I just want to know if maybe I'm coding something incorrectly.  Can you guys take a look?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "email@website.com";
$email_subject = "";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}


// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   submitted.');       
}


$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}


$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="contactform" action="contactform.php" method="post" class="well span11">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="span3" placeholder="Your First Name" required>
                <label for="Last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Last_name" class="span3" placeholder="Your Last Name" required>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="span3" placeholder="Your email address" required>
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <select id="subject" name="subject" class="span3">
                    <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                    <option value="service">Good Feedback</option>
                    <option value="suggestions">Poor Feedback</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <label for="comments">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="comments" class="input-xlarge span8" rows="12"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I also think I should mention that if I try to comment out the validation part I get an internal server error (Error 500), so that's why I'm thinking that something is wrong with my code.

Comment: which validation function is failing? your email and name checks will fail on legit data

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting. That way you'll get the actual PHP errors rather than an apache 500.  Put `ini_set('display_errors',1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` inside the `<?php ?>` tages above all the other PHP code, then report back with the errors and I'll help you.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` turned on? Might help you find the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: @AlexP: Great minds think alike!

Comment: Thanks guys.  I will make the change and then let you know.

Comment: @Phillip Still getting the Internal Server Error.  Where should I see the errors?  In the console?

Comment: @Keven: No, you should see them in the browser when you refresh the page, or in the PHP log file on the server if that is enabled.

Comment: oh, probably need to refresh the cache maybe??

Comment: @Phillip: Actually, no, now a blank page comes up (the url is the contactform.php).  Any reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea name="message" id="comments" class="input-xlarge span8" rows="12"></textarea>
```

You are expecting $_POST['comments'] in php but here you send name="message"

Another thing:

```
$_POST['last_name']
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="Last_name" class="span3" placeholder="Your Last Name" required>
```

in php, "last_name" != "Last_name"

Comment: That did it!  Thanks man, you were right.  I'm glad I could have a second pair of eyes to see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking if everything is set, at around line 27 or so, it says

`died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   submitted.');`

Are you sure it should not be

`die(We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   submitted.');`

(die instead of died)

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue.  'died' in this case is referring to the function died($error) stated previously.